# App was rejected for violating the Families policy Play store

Tags: android, google-play

My app is simple brain game which includes the AdMob advertisement.

when i posted the app for **First time upload** i selected the age group for everyone . then after fews days my app was rejected saying this app is not suitable for kids .

Then i changed the app name *Memory Game for Kids* to *Memory game* and selected the 18+ **Second time upload** , now play store again rejected the app  saying :

> **App rejected** Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the
>   Families policy. Before submitting your app for another review, check
>   the policy and make sure your app is compliant.

What to do next , please help me,,,,,i don't want to  remove advertisment .

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you must ensure you app content is suitable for [Family program](https://developer.android.com/google-play/guides/families).

If so, then take a look at this answer https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en.

You might have ads enabled that are not suitable for kids/family. If you opt-in for family program, you have to request for ads which are also suitable for kids and family also.

> Use the following code sample to set "max_ad_content_rating" and invoke tagForChildDirectedTreatment() to send child-directed ad requests in a mixed-audience app:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer , i'll try above solution.

Comment: .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)  is now deprecated but I don't see an Admob guide to a proper replacement

Answer (score 2):

According to latest documents:

```
//*** Digital content labels ***// https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7562142

RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
            .toBuilder()
            .setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
            .build();
//*** Digital content labels end ***//

MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

    }
});
```